# create json from a property definition in a class

Tags: gulp, gruntjs, task

I have a class that every now and then adds a new property, I am looking for a way to create an automatic task that at the time of creating a new property is also saved a json file with its description in Spanish. what is expected is:

```
class MyEmployee{
constructor(
  name: string, //@ Nombre
  apell: string,//@ Apellido
  segApell: string, @ Segundo Apellido
){}
}
```

automatic output

```
{
 "name": "Nombre",
 "apell": "Apellido",
 "segApell": "Segundo Apellido"

}
```